# Download file from google drive using c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to download a file from google drive through c#. But everytime i am running the code for downloading the file but i am unable to download it.
here is my code for download:

```
private static void DownloadFile(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService driveService)
        {

            var fileId = "//my file id for file on drive";
            var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
            // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
            // download is completed or failed.
            request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
                (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
                {
                    try
                    {


                        switch (progress.Status)
                        {
                            case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                    break;
                                }
                            case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                                    break;
                                }
                            case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                };
            request.Download(stream);

        }
```

Comment: please clarify what you mean by **unable to download it**  what is your error message

Comment: specify the error you are getting

Comment: @DaImTo  i am getting "Download Failed" as the output

Comment: Thats the message you have it outputting your going to have to get the response from google and show us that we cant debug it without knowing why the download failed.

Comment: @NitinSawant i m getting 'Download Failed' as the output and i dont know the reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Downloading Content, use `webContentLink` or might be Download Url return in File Get method. You can just use that link for download the file.

For more information please check [File Resource Object.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource)